# DirectX12 mips odd sized texture mips generation

Tags: 3d, directx, directx-11, hlsl, directx-12

Currently trying to break down this article for me: https://www.3dgep.com/learning-directx-12-4/. Cannot understand the odd-sized case. The sampling pattern picture presented in the article is not the one I get when drawing them by myself. Images in the article look like they show the second sample as if it was calculated as UV1 +(0.75, 0), but it's actually UV1+(0.5, 0).

Are my image of the pattern correct and the one in the article not? [image: My image of the sampling, odd width case]

Answer (score 0):

The picture in the article is actually correct (as in, it matches with the code they present). Your image has two mistakes, which is why it looks different:

- (0, 0) is not in the *center* of the top left pixel, but in the *top left corner* of said pixel
- The code in the article scales the UV coordinates by `TexelSize`, which (in their code) is one over the *destination* texture size. So, to get the pixel coordinates for your image, you would have to multiply 0.25 and 0.75 with the ratio of source texture size over destination texture size.

As an example, the first two samples (if the source texture width is 9 pixels) would be at (9 / 4) * 0.25 = 0.5625 and (9 / 4) * 0.75 = 1.6875, so in both cases a bit to the right of the center of the first and second pixel in the source image.

Note that, if you sample a texture in a shader, you don't multiply the UVs with the size of the texture you're sampling, which is why the shader code in the article only has (1 / 4) * 0.25 and (1 / 4) * 0.75. Scaling by the texture size just makes it easier to draw :)